# ASP.NET MVC: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false on some virtual machines

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms-authentication, httpcontext

I have been going through this weird issue on some of my virtual machines. It works perfectly fine on another!

When user email and password has been verified, I use SetAuthCookie to setup the httpcontext properties.

```
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(viewModel.Email, viewModel.RememberMe);
```

I use

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

method to check whether user is authenticated or not but this always returns null on few virtual machines while works perfectly fine on other. Are there any environment setting I am missing? Could anyone please help me to debug/fix this issue.

I figured out that it is returning Identity = Generic on machines where it doesn't work. It should return Identity = Forms as it does on another machine and also in web.config, the authentication mode is setup to Forms!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved. I had a domain=".localhost.com" for Forms properties in web config. I have removed it and worked fine!